# BBCode or WYSIWYG editor for non-technical people

Tags: wysiwyg

I am creating a forum for non-technical people, and I can't figure out if BBCode or a WYSIWYG editor is easier for them to use.

The forum is for craftsmen, and I am therefor in doubt if a BBCode editor would be too difficult to figure out.

Does any of you have any good suggestions on what to use?

Comment: IMHO, BBCode is the most useless invention every, and was solely invented to create another own, "cool" language. If you want to provide _no_ WYSIWYG editor, I recommend at least that you allow some other syntax like normal HTML or the syntax that Stack Overflow allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty obvious that, for the average person, a WYSIWYG editor is easier to use. If it was easier to write markup by hand, then there'd be no market for WYSIWYG editors at all.

Popular open source options are [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).